# methods not available

Tags: java, methods

There is a class CustomerData which contains various fields and set/get method for those fields.

```
class CustomerData{

 int ssn;
 int homePhone; 
 int officePhone;
 String product;
 String sameAsPrev=null;
 // set/get methods
}
```

I need to replace this class with class Customer. Customer class is in jar file. hence i can't modified. some fields of CustomerData is not available in Customer class and i need to call those fields on Customer Object.

there is a restriction that i can't add any class but just to replace CustomerData class with Customer.

in Controller after calling set methods on field they used map to store the data.

how can i get the values of those fields.

please give some suggestions...

Comment: Could you use a wrapper? Or maybe a containment?

Comment: If you have getters for all the fields, why is it you cannot access them from the Customer class?

Comment: Your question is not clear - you shall use a Customer object instead of a CustomerData object, but the Customer class does not offer enough information? Show your Customer class, show your Controller, maybe it gets clearer then.

Comment: If you don't understand what Tobiask means then read the FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Answer (score 0):

If the fields that are in your class but, which are not in the Customer class are mandatory, then you have two options:
Option 1 (isa, extends)
Extend the Customer class with your class.

```
public class CustomerDescendant
extends Customer
{
  ... stuff goes here
}
```

Option 2 (hasa, contains):
Contain the Customer class in your class.

```
public class CustomerWrapper
{
  private Customer customerInstance;

  ... stuff

  getFieldInCustomerClass()
  {
    return customerInstance.getFieldInQuestion();
  }

  ... stuff
}
```

Option 3 (bonus option):
Create a class with the fields that are required but, which are not in the Customer class.

```
public class FieldsNotInCustomerClass
{
  ... all fields that are not in the customer class, but which are required.
}
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. i am going to try it. and i will tell you its worked or not. thanks once again.